# How does Liferay determine which portlets to display on a page

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, portlet, portal

I'm currently trying to programmatically place and manipulate content (JournalArticle) on a page and facing some problems. The main issue is that I don't understand how Liferay knows which portlets are placed on a page.

I thought it would be like this:

---

- User opens page like: .../[group]/page
- Liferay looks in the `Layout` table for a layout that does match the `groupId` and `friendlyURL`
- Now it will parse the `typeSettings` column to get something like this:

  - column-1=56_INSTANCE_G2dgK2HoXq2l
  - So there is a JournalArticle in the first column
- Now get the `PortletPreferences` with the `plid`of the Layout and the `portletId` = 56_INSTANCE_G2dgK2HoXq2l
- In there is a XML which provides the `groupId`and `articleId`
- Get the JournalArticle with that `groupId` and `articleId`and display it.

---

But something seems to be missing. Say we add a new JournalArticle with (my personal favorite) `JournalArticleLocalService.addArticle(...)`.
Now, to add this to a page we do this:

```java
//get a new instanceId for the journalArticle
LayoutTypePortlet layoutTypePortlet = (LayoutTypePortlet) layout.getLayoutType();
String portletInstanceId = layoutTypePortlet.addPortletId( userId, portletId, "column-1", 1, false);

//gather some other infos
long companyId = article.getCompanyId();
long ownerId = PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_ID_DEFAULT;
int onwerType = PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_TYPE_LAYOUT;
long plid = layout.getPlid();

//get the preferences with the plid and instanceId
PortletPreferences preferences = PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.getPreferences( companyId, ownerId, ownerType, plid, portletInstanceId);

//set the prefs
preferences.setValue( "articleId", article.getArticleId() );
preferences.setValue( "groupId", String.valueOf( article.getGroupId() ) );

//store updated prefs back to db
PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.updatePreferences( ownerId, ownerType, plid, portletInstanceId, preferences);

//update the layout (is this necessary?)
LayoutLocalService.updateLayout( layout.getGroupId, layout.isPrivateLayout(), layout.getLayoutId(), layout.getTypeSettings() );

//finally fire PortletLayoutListener
Portlet portlet = PortletLocalServiceUtil.getPortletById( companyId, portletInstanceId );
PortletLayoutListener portletLayoutListener = portlet.getPortletLayoutListenerInstance();
if ( portletLayoutListener != null ) {
    portletLayoutListener.onAddToLayout( portletInstanceId, plid );
}
```

When I run this code, everthing looks fine the db tables. If I follow the way I described above, Liferay should display that new JournalArticle on the page. But it does not.

To prove my theory, I manually added an Article and then removed it from the TypeSettings of the Layout (using SQL Developer). Liferay still showed the article after refreshing the page. Only after restarting the server it was gone (caching).
But even when I restart the server, my programmatically added Articles do not show up.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance, ~Fabi

*I'm still running Liferay 6.1.20EE*

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to ask something like _How to add a preconfigured WebContent portlet programmatically to a page?_ Your original question is highly version specific and I don't think that you have to dig that deep in the internals (which you may understand by inspecting / debugging the corresponding configuration and view actions).

Comment: thx. I'll try to debug it. This might help: http://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Page+Rendering